# How to match exact value using match function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cell value 0.00%  in a row and also I have 0 in before 0.00% in same row .

when I try to match `=MATCH(0.00%,$B22:$EU22,0)`. It will return 0 value Position  not a 0.00% Position. Any one suggest to me .

Comment: What's the numeric difference between those two?

Comment: Just different of cells format?

Comment: I want just get position of 0.00% ignore 0 .

Comment: You'll struggle to do this because 0 and 0.00% represent the same value in Excel ie the number zero but differ in format. The `=MATCH()` function only matches on values and not on values and formats combined together.

Comment: Yes DMM can you please give me solution of it ? how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Before the match, you need to convert the values in your range $B22:$EU22 to text first. Then, either use the following

```
=MATCH("0.00%",$B22:$EU22,0) 
=MATCH("0.00",$B22:$EU22,0)
=MATCH("0",$B22:$EU22,0)
```

Or

=MATCH(TEXT(B20,"0.00%"),$B26:$EU26,0)

=MATCH(TEXT(C20,"0.00"),$B26:$EU26,0)

=MATCH(TEXT(D20,"0"),$B26:$EU26,0)

to find the match position. Cells B20, C20, and D20 are blank or zero.

[image: The images show the snapshots of both ways]